# Enzyme Click on Button Inside Component Inside Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, storybook

Im working on a React Javascript Storybook right now and Im trying to figure out how to get enzyme to click a button inside of a component inside a component. So in other words this is the structure

```
<Component 1>
   <Component 2>
    <Button>
   </Component 2>
</Component 1>
```

And I want to click on the Button inside of compoenent 2. So far I have this

```
storesOf("Press the button",module).add("Button press:,() => {
    let output;
    specs(() => describe('clicked',function () {
        it("Should do the thing",function () {
            output = mount(<Component 1/>);
            output.find("Button").at(0).simulate("click")
        })
    }));

    const Inst = () => output.instance();
    return <Inst/>;
});
```

Does anyone have any advice? I should also add that as of current it does not find any buttons to click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Enzyme documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#2-a-react-component-constructor) you can use a React component constructor as your selector. You can do something like this:

```
output = mount(<Component1 />);
output.find(Component2).find(Button).simulate("click")
```